# java pdf file download using ajax request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am using Spring MVC. I don't want to show my URL in browser, since in am passing the id in it. I am using AJAX request,and I am using jquery.fileDownload.js file from http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/ URL to download file

my javascript code is

function print(value)
{

var myurl='PropertyTaxRegistration.html?PrintReport&assid='+value;

$.fileDownload(myurl, {

```
successCallback: function (url) { 

    alert('You just got a file download dialog or ribbon for this URL :' + url);
},
failCallback: function (html, url) {

    alert('Your file download just failed for this URL:' + url + '\r\n' +
            'Here was the resulting error HTML: \r\n' + html
            );
} }); }
```

and my java code is

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jrxmlFileLocation);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataCollection));
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, (OutputStream) response.getOutputStream());
        //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, (OutputStream) response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close(); return true;
```

My going in java class properly.
but in each each case it is going in error i.e,failCallback function and give error message;

Please help with my error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _I don't want to show my URL in browser, since in am passing the id in it_ - this is a very bad design, security-wise.  Just because the URL is not shown in the browser, it doesn't mean that it's not visible to the end-user.

Comment: I want to hide my id value through ajax request from end user.

Comment: As long as that ID appears **anywhere** the end user will be able to see it.

Comment: No sir, my url **var myurl='PropertyTaxRegistration.html?PrintReport&assid='+value;** will be hidden it will not get show to end user, throught which i can pass my url and retrive data

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what is generally visible to the user.  Any browser can show to the end user ALL url's that it's fetching, whether from the address bar, AJAX, images, css, javascript, etc.  If a browser is loading a URL - from any source - the end user can see what the url is.

Comment: You should not rely on this mechanism to authenticate/validate the user.  Once a user has authenticated, keep the right information in the session/cookies - this way you won't need to validate the user using a value in the URL - which is easy to change.